# How can I avoid rendering a file in the pages directory with NextJS?

Tags: next.js

Suppose I have `pages/foo/index.tsx` and I want which uses `pages/foo/helper.tsx` as a helper. Next will then render `pages/foo/helper.tsx` in response to a `GET /foo/helper` request instead of a 404.. I don't want that to happen. Doing `_helper.tsx` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Any good reason you want to keep it under `pages` folder? You also can consider to create another folder and import it into your page component instead

Comment: @NickVu I like the colocation. If `helper.tsx` is only used for `pages/foo/index.tsx`, I like putting it in `pages/foo` because it's easy to find and it's purpose/scope is clear.

Answer (score 2):

**NEXT.JS VERSION 13**

From [Next.js 13's routing](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/fundamentals), we can have a new app structure with colocation

You can name your page like `page.*` (the file extension can be `.jsx`, `.js`, `.tsx`, `.ts`), Next.js will understand `page.*` is for the page component automatically.

According to your path `/foo/page` and along with `helper.tsx`, we can have the below file structure

```
app
 └─foo
    ├─page.tsx
    └─helper.tsx
```

---

**THIS ANSWER IS FOR NEXT.JS BELOW VERSION 13**

If your helper file does not have any JSX-related parts, you can rename your file to `helper.ts`, and add the page extension config to `next.config.js` like below

```
module.exports = {
  pageExtensions: ['jsx', 'tsx'], //only allow page files with file extensions `jsx` or `tsx`
}
```

If you cannot change the helper file extension, you can consider using another page extension configurations

```
module.exports = {
  pageExtensions: ['page.jsx', 'page.tsx'], //only allow page files with file extensions `page.jsx` or `page.tsx`
}
```

And then modify all your page files' names to become

```
yourPageName.page.tsx
yourPageName.page.jsx
```

You can check [this document](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory) to understand `pageExtensions` more.